# Haskell Evaluating Arithmetic Expressions and Assigning Variables

Tags: haskell, expression, ghci, expr

I have a datatype called expr as follows:

```
data Expr = C Float | Expr :+ Expr | Expr :- Expr | Expr :* Expr| Expr :/ Expr
```

What I want to do is extend the Expr datatype to allow variables and 'let' expressions

Comment: `let x e1 e2` is essentially `(lambda (x) e2) e1`. I don't think you could trivially extend to that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass around the active bindings, in what is traditionally called  "the environment":

```
evaluate :: Environment -> Expr -> Float
```

There are many ways to represent an environment.
You need two operations: looking up a binding to get a value, and extending it with a new binding.

```
lookup :: Environment -> String -> Float
extend :: Environment -> String -> Float -> Environment
```

Implementation left as an exercise.

Comment: Your functions will be a bit more idiomatic and convenient to use if you move the `Environment` to be their last parameter. See `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`, for example.

Comment: (That change also makes the change to, e.g., `evaluate :: Expr -> State Environment Float` more natural).

Comment: @amalloy Why `State`? Isn't `Reader` the appropriate monad? If we evaluate `let x=5 in ((let x = 1 in x) + x)`  using the state monad in the "straightforward" way we get the wrong result, I think.

Comment: Yes, `Reader` is better. I thought `State` had some method like `local`, but that's in `Reader`. But the same point about argument order applies.

Comment: Neither `Reader` nor `State` are appropriate for a novice.

Comment: @molbdnilo Statements like that probably scare off more novices than actual exposure *to* the `Reader` monad.